# CMS Editor does not display a language in Language dropdown for Content Editor role, but displays for Admin role

Tags: content-editor, multilingual

For Content Editor I have checked the access, he has Language Read and Language Write for all the languages, except **de** all other languages appear for Content Editor. Please let me know if I have missed any access for it to be enabled for Content Editor role. Language de is not appearing in the dropdown.
Thanks

[image: Languages] [image: Access Viewer]

Comment: Is it the same in Experience Editor when you try to change language from the "version" ribbon? Which Sitecore version? Any custom modules? SXA?

Comment: Hi, Yes the de language appears in Experience Editor, but not in Content Editor. I am using Sitecore 8.2.

Comment: No Custom modules, SXA, third party tools installed.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it's not the case but have you tried to enlarge the size of that language selector in Content Editor using this "3 dots" icon in bottom left? Just to be sure it's not a styling issue bug?

Comment: If you open "/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx" and search for "getContentLanguages" pipeline, does it have any processors?

Comment: Just tried enlarging the size and inspected the html of Language dropdown, still it does not show the language. Only the below line of code is there for getContentLanguages in config. <getContentLanguages help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetContentLanguages.GetContentLanguagesProcessor."/>

Comment: And if you add a "DE" version as admin, does it show in Content Editor then? That screen from Access Viewer, it's for that particular user you're testing with? or for Content Editor role?

Comment: I have tested using multiple admin role users, I am able to add/edit the content in Content Editor for DE. Also tested using multiple users with Content Editor role, not able to see the language in DropDown.

Comment: @SathishKumar Please open developer tool in browser, go to network tab (All). Now click on the Languages dropdown in Content Editor and note the request in network tab You may see like https://sitecoreinstancedomain/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=Gallery.Languages&id=%7B110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7D&la=en&vs=1&db=master&align=right Right click and open in new tab to see if any error.

Comment: @GuptaSandeepkumar No errors, I am able to see the language dropdown without DE. Thanks